# Can data change while export?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me explain scenario first,
Let's say we've some transaction tables for sales purposes. And data can be inserted or updated as per user's actions on a particular sales application. Since the data can be used for financial purposes, finance department wants to have data which has been created or updated till 12 noon. But we cannot stop the program. So, data can be updated after 12noon as well.

Now, I've a complex select statement. Which generates lots of data.

Now, when we generate the data and then started to export it into CSV, it's taking lot of time. More than half hour.

So, my question is during export, if users are using application and thus data is getting updated, does that also affects the export functionality of generated data? Does the generated data can get changed during export? Since SQL only generates the visible data at first and loads another data as per pagination changes.

If so, how to control such behavior?

Comment: What do you want to control? Oracle doesn't allow dirty reads, for more details on concurrent modifications see [Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-4BD4DFD6-DAEA-41B2-BB56-7135568F0548)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your "pagination" is a *single SQL statement executed only once* and then *fetched* progressively, oracle will construct consistent read (CR) buffers by applying undo from any changes that happen after your SQL starts (it finds SCNs in the block ITLs that are greater than its own transaction start SCN, then reads undo and applies undo records to reconstruct how the block looked at the point of your transaction's start SCN), so that you get the same results you would if the table were 100% idle. It's a beautiful thing (though it can cause some severe performance issues in some cases) and an important feature of Oracle.

**However**, if your "pagination" is a *series* of SQL statements (using the `WHERE` clause programmatically constructed to accomplish pagination) for any reason, then each of them is CR guaranteed consistent individually, but **not** between them. You will get inconsistent data if that's the method you're using and others are updating the table.

Therefore make sure your extract is a single atomic execution. Multiple *fetches* after an exec is okay, but multiple *execs* are not.

Answer (score 2):

No, the data will not change. When you run a query in Oracle, it gets you the data of that very moment.

Even if your query runs for hours and other sessions change data and commit these changes, your query will be oblivious to these changes. Oracle will use its internal change history, to make sure you get the data as of the timestamp you started your query.

Comment: This is correct, but Oracle's ability to do this has a practical limitation: the UNDO records (the internal change history) that allow Oracle to reverse changes to the data for the sake of maintaining the logical consistency of your query results *must* be available. If too many changes to the underlying data happen before your query is complete, needed UNDO records may be overwritten and Oracle will raise an ORA-01555 error in your query/export session. This will prevent your query from completing but will not affect other users or the overall application data consistency.